# 2 tables (inner join) versus 1 table (simple select)

Tags: mysql, performance, inner-join

What is the best?
Have two related tables and query the data through an inner join with id columns, or have a table already with the string and making a simple query? (Think in tons of records)

Example (Inner Join)

```
Table1
ID - Value
1 - AAA
2 - BBB
3 - CCC
4 - DDD
```

...INNER JOIN ...where value = 'BBB'

```
Table 2
ID - Table1_id
21645 - 1
45465 - 2
78787 - 2
68797 - 4
```

========================== 
Example (Simple select)

```
Table 2
ID - Table1_value
21645 - AAA
45465 - BBB
78787 - BBB
68797 - DDD
where table1_value = 'BBB'
```

In the first example do I use less space while in the second example less processing?

Comment: You should read up on DB design and normalization. And the answer is: Use a join

Comment: You should follow first approach

Comment: Could you post both the queries in the question?

Comment: @juergend, all-be-it a bad example, I don't see any reason to use a join here without more context.

Comment: "Tons" = thousands --> not a big difference.  "Tons" = millions --> Let's see the rest of the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; I suspect there may be valid reasons for having (or not having) 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking in some case of denormalization. Since i dont have how to predict the result without populating and testing, i choose the inner join. Thx.